# Selecting Record based on last hour of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

[image][image]Basically I have a database that retrieves data each minute of the day. This has occurred over the past three years in my company. I am looking for a query that would pull all records each day at 11:00:00PM. I do have a timestamp column and have tried the following but it does not generate any results. The Timestamp format is as follows 2011-10-13 16:59:00.000.

Select * from WaterUsage
Where Timestamp like '%23:00:00%'

Thank You.

This following formula seems to work but leaves out a few days...Not sure why..

```
 with cte as
(


  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by datediff(d, 0, Timestmp) order by timestmp desc) as rn 
  from WaterUsage
  )
select *
from cte  
where rn = 1
```

This also works as well if I were to retrieve yearly results within a timeframe.

```
Select * from WaterUsage where TimeStmp > '2011' and TimeStmp < '2012'
```

Comment: You can share table sample ?

Comment: @4EACH just wanted to know the same. Really unsure about the Timestamp datatype now.

Comment: I need one more reputation point to post images. I have it all screen shotted.

Comment: @riceformvp You have to help us to help you :)

Comment: Thank you guys :) I am posting the image now.

Comment: Image is in the original post.

Comment: Can you show the create statement used to create the table as well?

Comment: In my answer i wrote Timestamp, did you replace it to TimeStmp?

Comment: Yes I did and I don't have access to the create statement. These databases were handed to me.

Comment: We just need to know what format the TimeStmp column ist. Sometimes SQLEditors preformat these. Is it a VARCHAR, INT or DATE type?

Comment: It is a Date type :)

Comment: Errrr Bad answer ! Date type holds date only :)

Comment: ERrrr. I am not too familiar with SQL. I can do basic functions..:(

Comment: Run `DESCRIBE WaterUsage;` and post results here

Comment: I have added an image posting the results of each variable.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is to put white space at the beginning cause timestamp is Date + Time.

```
Select * from WaterUsage Where TimeStmp like '% 23:%'`
```

Another way:

```
Select * from WaterUsage Where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TimeStmp)%86400 > 82800
```

You need to check performance for these two options.

Comment: That executes but doesn't provide any results.

Comment: That makes my answer more correct because the Timestamp column doesnt store dates

Comment: Both of them don't provide any results?

Comment: Correct. I updated my post and provided an example that does work but some days seem to be missing. Also If were to retrieve based on year, the following works...Select * from WaterUsage
where TimeStmp > '2011' and TimeStmp < '2012'

Comment: I have screenshotted the variable types for each field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get records at 23:00

```
Select * from WaterUsage 
where datepart(hour , TimeStmp) = 23 and datepart(minute , TimeStmp) = 00
```

If you want to get records from 23:00 until end of day

```
Select * from WaterUsage 
where datepart(hour , TimeStmp) = 23
```

Answer (score -1):

Guessing that your timestamp column is a VARCHAR column you could do

```
Select * from WaterUsage Where TimeStmp like '23:%'
```

The expression `Timestamp like '23:%'` only evaluates to true if the timestamp string starts with '23:'. So every timestamp between 23:00:00 and 23:59:59 would match it.

**Attention (Only applies if timestamp column only stores time and no date)**
Dont put a % in front of the 23 because then the expression would also match 03:23:50 (just an example)

**If there is a leading date in the timestamp column then the correct query would be

```
Select * from WaterUsage Where TimeStmp like '% 23:%'
```

Just to make sure you include a whitespace between the % and 23

Comment: Right. I'm just trying to generate results at 11:59:00 PM for each day then. That will do.

Comment: Correct answer is to put space at the beginning cause timestamp is Date + Time. **Select * from WaterUsage Where Timestamp like '% 23:%'**

Comment: Did not know about the format of the timestamp. Yeah with the date as prefix you are totally right. But the comment on your answer suggest that the Timestamp column consists only of the time

Comment: I have attached an image describing each field variable.